# How is theTable populated in an ActiveMQMapMessage? Can its contents be retrieved?

Tags: groovy, activemq-classic, geb

I have just written my first GEB/Spock functional tests with Groovy v2.4.12 using ActiveMQ v5.14.5 inside a Docker container. I can successfully create and send a MapMessage to ActiveMQ. I call that message the **expectedMM** because, per requirements, I'm expecting to get back the same data in this particular instance.

I can also retrieve the resulting MapMessage from a different queue with no problems. I call that my **actualMM**.

The problem I'm facing is that

```
assert( expectedMM == actualMM )
```

fails because property values and timestamps are obviously different... many fields are different **EXCEPT** for what is contained in '*theTable*.' That is the data I'm interested in.

1. How is theTable created/populated in a MapMessage? Is it directly affected by the un/marshalling process? (It didn't sound like I had to unmarshall any resulting map?)
2. Is there a way to retrieve its contents with a getter?
3. If not, do I really need to get each of the fields/keys/names I need one by one? If so, then so be it (hope not!). I just need to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. Below is what I've tried so far.

   - ActiveMQ API:  [ActiveMQMapMessage](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.14.5/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQMapMessage.html).
   - Google searches:  [ActiveMQMapMessage theMap etc](https://www.google.com/search?q=ActiveMQMapMessage%20theTable)
   - Calling *getObject( 'theTable' )* on either map returns null.
   - Printing all key/value pairs with *getMapNames()* doesn't include *theTable* (which explains the null above)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered sending a Xml or JSON payload using a TextMessage? MapMessages are really specific to JMS, and are problematic due to the fact that you have to know the specific types of each field, and perform a lot of type checking when retrieving values.

Sending Xml or JSON as a TextMessage decouples you from the broker and provides more flexibility for integration down the road.

Answer (score 0):

To check the values of two MapMessage instances you can get the list of Map elements from the Message and then compare those two and then of course compare the elements of the map

The MapMessage API provide the 'getMapNames' method to return an enumeration of string values that comprise the elements of the map, and then you can use 'itemExists' to check for its presence or call 'getObject' to obtain the objectified value of the items given in the result of 'getMapNames'.  Have a look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html) for MapMessage to see how to work with one.

You can of course [cheat](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/d8c80a98212ee5d73a281483a2f8b3f517465f62/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQMapMessage.java#L826) and get the Map itself but that only work if the two MapMessage instances are both of the ActiveMQ type.